# JMS servlet implementation on Tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, jms, activemq-classic, tomcat8

I want to implement JMS server on tomcat, I have all configurations to setup JMS but I made some mistakes,

I have 3 classes (`JMSServlet`, `JMSSender` and `JMSReceiver`)
`JMSServlet` don't handle my http requests and don't reply as throw exception from `startInternal()` method in catalina.jar in **apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1**\libs

```
*java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BasicJMS]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:852)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1390)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)*
```

Comment: You're missing the root cause of the reason it failed to start.

Comment: ok I see, my root cause was [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BasicJMS' did not find a matching property, And I handel it , I opened the server configuration. Under server options check ‘Publish module contents to separate XML files’ checkbox. Restart my server. This time my page will come without any issues.

Comment: Include the full stacktrace in the question itself.

Comment: when any answer helps you (including your own) [click the green checkmark to mark it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Also takes one minute for the [tour] to understand how this site works

Answer (score 0):

I handel it , I opened the server configuration. Under server options check ‘Publish module contents to separate XML files’ checkbox. Restart my server. This time my page will come without any issues.